# Making a binary search tree into a template

Tags: c++, templates, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

So, I've made a binary search tree, but now I'm stuck, as I have to make it into a template, yet my knowledge of templates are rather limited and if someone could, I'd appreciate it if they could "spoonfeed" me how to convert the tree into one that would work for any numerical data, thanks in advance!

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "bst.h"

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    BST tree;
    tree.insert(8);
    tree.insert(25);
    tree.insert(99);
    tree.insert(20);
    tree.insert(25);
    tree.insert(20);
    tree.insert(2);
    tree.insert(89);
    tree.insert(15);
    tree.insert(10);
    tree.insert(30);
    tree.insert(50);
    tree.displayorder();



    int number;

    int Inputnumber;
    while (true){
        cout << "Choose what you want to do: " << endl << "1# Insert" << endl << "2# Display Orders" << endl <<  "3# Search" << endl << "4# Delete" << endl << endl << endl;
        cin >> Inputnumber;
        if (Inputnumber==1){
            cout << endl << "Enter the number you want inserted: ";
            cin >> number;
            tree.insert(number);
            cout << endl << endl << endl;
        }
        if (Inputnumber==2){
            cout<<"Display Orders: " << endl;
            tree.displayorder();
            cout << endl << endl << endl;
        }

        if (Inputnumber==3){
            cout<<"Enter the number you want to search for: ";
            cin >> number;
            tree.search(number);
            cout << endl << endl << endl;
        }
        if (Inputnumber==4){
            cout << "Enter the number you want to remove: ";
            cin >> number;
            tree.remove(number);
            cout << endl << endl << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

**Bst.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "bst.h"

using namespace std;

BST::node* BST::makeEmpty(node* tree)
{
    if(tree == NULL)
        return NULL;
    {
        makeEmpty(tree->left);
        makeEmpty(tree->right);
        delete tree;
    }
    return NULL;
}

BST::node* BST::insert(int x, node* tree)
{
    if(tree == NULL)
    {
        tree = new node;
        tree->data = x;
        tree->left = tree->right = NULL;
    }
    else if(x < tree->data)
        tree->left = insert(x, tree->left);
    else if(x >= tree->data)
        tree->right = insert(x, tree->right);
    return tree;
}

BST::node* BST::findMin(node* tree)
{
    if(tree == NULL)
        return NULL;
    else if(tree->left == NULL)
        return tree;
    else
        return findMin(tree->left);
}

BST::node* BST::findMax(node* tree)
{
    if(tree == NULL)
        return NULL;
    else if(tree->right == NULL)
        return tree;
    else
        return findMax(tree->right);
}

BST::node* BST::remove(int x, node* tree)
{
    node* temp;
    if(tree == NULL)
        return NULL;
    else if(x < tree->data)
        tree->left = remove(x, tree->left);
    else if(x > tree->data)
        tree->right = remove(x, tree->right);
    else if(tree->left && tree->right)
    {
        temp = findMin(tree->right);
        tree->data = temp->data;
        tree->right = remove(tree->data, tree->right);
    }
    else
    {
        temp = tree;
        if(tree->left == NULL)
            tree = tree->right;
        else if(tree->right == NULL)
            tree = tree->left;
        delete temp;
    }

    return tree;
}

void BST::inorder(node* tree)
{
    if(tree == NULL){
        return;
    }
    inorder(tree->left);
    cout << tree->data << " ";
    inorder(tree->right);
}

void BST::preorder(node* tree)
{
    if(tree == NULL){
        return;
    }
    cout << tree->data << " ";
    inorder(tree->left);
    inorder(tree->right);
}



void BST::postorder(node* tree)
{
    if(tree == NULL){
        return;
    }
    inorder(tree->left);
    inorder(tree->right);
    cout << tree->data << " ";
}

BST::node* BST::find(node* tree, int x)
{
    if(tree == NULL)
        return NULL;
    else if(x < tree->data)
        return find(tree->left, x);
    else if(x > tree->data)
        return find(tree->right, x);
    else
        return tree;
}

BST::BST()
{
    root = NULL;
}

BST::~BST()
{
    root = makeEmpty(root);
}

void BST::insert(int x)
{
    root = insert(x, root);
}

void BST::remove(int x)
{
    root = remove(x, root);
}

void BST::displayorder()
{
    inorder(root);
    cout << endl;
    preorder(root);
    cout << endl;
    postorder(root);
    cout << endl << endl;
}

void BST::search(int x)
{
    if(root = find(root, x)){
        cout << endl << "Found!" << endl;
    }
    else{
        cout << endl << "Not Found!" << endl;
    }
}
```

**Bst.h**

```
#ifndef BST_H
#define BST_H



class BST
{
    struct node
    {
        int data;
        node* left;
        node* right;
    };

    node* root;

    node* makeEmpty(node* tree);

    node* insert(int x, node* tree);

    node* findMin(node* tree);

    node* findMax(node* tree);

    node* remove(int x, node* tree);

    void inorder(node* tree);

    void preorder(node* tree);



    void postorder(node* tree);



public:
    BST();

    ~BST();


    node* find(node* tree, int x);

    void insert(int x);

    void remove(int x);

    void displayorder();

    void search(int x);
};

#endif // BST_H
```

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: No. This site is heavily against *spoonfeeding*. Figure out where lies the problem, provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ask a good question

Comment: oversimplified: replace "int" with "value_type" and put "template <typename value_type>" in front of everything. You can now make instances of BST<int>. Put everything in bst.h  Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do that by using the following changes:

In your BST.h file, add the following above the class decleration:

```
template < typename T >
class BST {
   [...]
}
```

Then, foreach method definition, change it to:

```
template < typename T >
typename BST<T>::node* BST<T>::makeEmpty(BST<T>::node* tree)
{
    if(tree == NULL)
        return NULL;
    {
        makeEmpty(tree->left);
        makeEmpty(tree->right);
        delete tree;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Then, search and replace `int` with `T` in both `BST.h` and `BST.cpp`.

And then in your `main.cpp` change the variable to `BST<int> tree`.

The result should be this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template < typename T >
class BST
{
    struct node
    {
        T data;
        node* left;
        node* right;
    };

    node* root;

    node* makeEmpty(node* tree);

    node* insert(T x, node* tree);

    node* findMin(node* tree);

    node* findMax(node* tree);

    node* remove(T x, node* tree);

    void inorder(node* tree);

    void preorder(node* tree);



    void postorder(node* tree);



public:
    BST();

    ~BST();


    node* find(node* tree, T x);

    void insert(T x);

    void remove(T x);

    void displayorder();

    void search(T x);
};

template < typename T >
typename BST<T>::node* BST<T>::makeEmpty(BST<T>::node* tree)
{
    if(tree == NULL)
        return NULL;
    {
        makeEmpty(tree->left);
        makeEmpty(tree->right);
        delete tree;
    }
    return NULL;
}

template < typename T >
typename BST<T>::node* BST<T>::insert(T x, BST<T>::node* tree)
{
    if(tree == NULL)
    {
        tree = new node;
        tree->data = x;
        tree->left = tree->right = NULL;
    }
    else if(x < tree->data)
        tree->left = insert(x, tree->left);
    else if(x >= tree->data)
        tree->right = insert(x, tree->right);
    return tree;
}

template < typename T >
typename BST<T>::node* BST<T>::findMin(BST<T>::node* tree)
{
    if(tree == NULL)
        return NULL;
    else if(tree->left == NULL)
        return tree;
    else
        return findMin(tree->left);
}

template < typename T >
typename BST<T>::node* BST<T>::findMax(BST<T>::node* tree)
{
    if(tree == NULL)
        return NULL;
    else if(tree->right == NULL)
        return tree;
    else
        return findMax(tree->right);
}

template < typename T >
typename BST<T>::node* BST<T>::remove(T x, BST<T>::node* tree)
{
    node* temp;
    if(tree == NULL)
        return NULL;
    else if(x < tree->data)
        tree->left = remove(x, tree->left);
    else if(x > tree->data)
        tree->right = remove(x, tree->right);
    else if(tree->left && tree->right)
    {
        temp = findMin(tree->right);
        tree->data = temp->data;
        tree->right = remove(tree->data, tree->right);
    }
    else
    {
        temp = tree;
        if(tree->left == NULL)
            tree = tree->right;
        else if(tree->right == NULL)
            tree = tree->left;
        delete temp;
    }

    return tree;
}

template < typename T >
void BST<T>::inorder(BST<T>::node* tree)
{
    if(tree == NULL){
        return;
    }
    inorder(tree->left);
    cout << tree->data << " ";
    inorder(tree->right);
}

template < typename T >
void BST<T>::preorder(BST<T>::node* tree)
{
    if(tree == NULL){
        return;
    }
    cout << tree->data << " ";
    inorder(tree->left);
    inorder(tree->right);
}


template < typename T >
void BST<T>::postorder(BST<T>::node* tree)
{
    if(tree == NULL){
        return;
    }
    inorder(tree->left);
    inorder(tree->right);
    cout << tree->data << " ";
}

template < typename T >
typename BST<T>::node* BST<T>::find(BST<T>::node* tree, T x)
{
    if(tree == NULL)
        return NULL;
    else if(x < tree->data)
        return find(tree->left, x);
    else if(x > tree->data)
        return find(tree->right, x);
    else
        return tree;
}

template < typename T >
BST<T>::BST()
{
    root = NULL;
}

template < typename T >
BST<T>::~BST()
{
    root = makeEmpty(root);
}

template < typename T >
void BST<T>::insert(T x)
{
    root = insert(x, root);
}

template < typename T >
void BST<T>::remove(T x)
{
    root = remove(x, root);
}

template < typename T >
void BST<T>::displayorder()
{
    inorder(root);
    cout << endl;
    preorder(root);
    cout << endl;
    postorder(root);
    cout << endl << endl;
}

template < typename T >
void BST<T>::search(T x)
{
    if(root = find(root, x)){
        cout << endl << "Found!" << endl;
    }
    else{
        cout << endl << "Not Found!" << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    BST<int> tree;
    tree.insert(8);
    tree.insert(25);
    tree.insert(99);
    tree.insert(20);
    tree.insert(25);
    tree.insert(20);
    tree.insert(2);
    tree.insert(89);
    tree.insert(15);
    tree.insert(10);
    tree.insert(30);
    tree.insert(50);
    tree.displayorder();



    int number;

    int Inputnumber;
    while (true){
        cout << "Choose what you want to do: " << endl << "1# Insert" << endl << "2# Display Orders" << endl <<  "3# Search" << endl << "4# Delete" << endl << endl << endl;
        cin >> Inputnumber;
        if (Inputnumber==1){
            cout << endl << "Enter the number you want inserted: ";
            cin >> number;
            tree.insert(number);
            cout << endl << endl << endl;
        }
        if (Inputnumber==2){
            cout<<"Display Orders: " << endl;
            tree.displayorder();
            cout << endl << endl << endl;
        }

        if (Inputnumber==3){
            cout<<"Enter the number you want to search for: ";
            cin >> number;
            tree.search(number);
            cout << endl << endl << endl;
        }
        if (Inputnumber==4){
            cout << "Enter the number you want to remove: ";
            cin >> number;
            tree.remove(number);
            cout << endl << endl << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While the information provided by this answer are most probably correct, I think we **should never** spoonfeed someone, especially when OP directly asks us to. This is a Q&A site, not code-provider one. This kind of behaviour leads to more and more people coming here and asking for pute code

Comment: @Fureeish, thanks for the advise, I will remember it for the next time.